# Cypress visit page with Bearer token

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to visit a page with a Bearer token, but it does not seem to work. When I use Postman, I am able to visit the page, but if I try to use code it does not.

I tried

```
cy.visit({
      url: '/',
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    })
```

With the authorization. I also tried `Cypress.env` and setting the `localStorage`, but none seem to work.

Comment: Are you hardcoding the value here in place of `${token}`? Also what is the error you are getting, add a screenshot.

Comment: I generate the Bearer token somewhere else and assign it to the `token` variable.

Comment: Can you log the token just before `cy.visit` to check if you are getting the token correctly. `cy.log(token)`

Comment: So the token did indeed not set, I made it a async axios request and now it does, the page still does not get the Bearer token.

Comment: Hi. I do suspect the `token` is simply empty at the point you call for it. You mention setting it in the `localStorage`. Did you use `request` and  `onBeforeLoad` callback function for that? Also, what happens if you provide the `username` and `password` in the auth object for your `visit` command? PS: screenshots and some logs will be more than helpful to understand the problem

Comment: So, the token does work now, but apparently the `cy.visit()` function does not support Bearer tokens. Is there a workaround or so?